# Not able to select desired value form dropdown while running webdriver script

Tags: select, webdriver, dropdown

On running webdriver code control finds the dropdown clicks on it but  selection of a value does not occur. I tried with "select by index" and "select by value" methods but no use. I think it sof type bootstrap dropdown.most  posts direct to  usage of aforesaid functions but im unable to use it . any help will be greatly appreciated.
    
    
    50
    100
    200
    300
    400
    500

Comment: your question is very vague, without you code and html snippet people won't be able to help you. Also what framework, language you are using ?

Comment: select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="recordnumber">
<option value="? string: ?"/>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
<option value="200">200</option>
<option value="300">300</option>
<option value="400">400</option>
<option value="500">500</option>
</select>

Answer (score 0):

We really need more information, including what programming language you are using, what code you are executing, and the HTML you are executing against. Looking at your comment in your original question, and without knowing any of the aforementioned, all I can suggest is selecting the times with XPATH. In Python it would be something like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@ng-model='recordnumber']/option[@value='300']").click()  # this would select the "300" item
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your effort but i found the solution . just  we need to click on the dropdown and call sendKeys("value to be entered into the dropdown").

Eg: drp=findElement(By.xpath("dropdown element locator").click();
    drp.sendKeys("value to shown in dropdown");